# Success callback after OData .create request

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm creating simple SAP Fiori application using OData v2 model.
I've done implementation of .create(...) request and it works on backend system, but I have a problem with success callback function.

After new object creation I want to display Message Toast with its number and go back to previous view.

How can I use objects from _createNotification function inside success / error (_onBatchError) callback?

```js
_createNotification: function() {

  var oModel = this.getModel();
  var that = this; 
  // ....

  oModel.create("/NotificationHeaderSet", oNotification, {
    
    success: function(oData, oResponse) {
   MessageToast.show(oData.NotificationNo);  // How to get i18n ?
      // this.getRouter().navTo("worklist", {}, true);
 },
    error: this._onBatchError
  });

}
```

`this, that, oModel` are undefined and `sap.ui.core.getCore().getModel()` gives null (outside this callback default / i18n model is handled fine)

Probably it is some dummy error, but I'm out of ideas.

Many thanks in advance.
Jakub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with jQuery.proxy it should work:

```js
_createNotification: function() {

  var oModel = this.getModel();
  var that = this; 
  // ....

  oModel.create("/NotificationHeaderSet", oNotification, {
    
    success: jQuery.proxy(function(oData, oResponse) {
   MessageToast.show(oData.NotificationNo);  // How to get i18n ?
      this.getRouter().navTo("worklist", {}, true);
 }, this),
    error: this._onBatchError
  });

}
```